# how to delete certain row values ( not null) in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

so I got a IOT dataset and I want to remove certain rows based on the 'Value' column values ( **they are not null values** ). For eg -

[PFA the screenshot of the dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H8QOM.png)

so basically I want to remove all the rows having the 'Data Lost' in the 'Value' column. There are 50k+ records in this dataset and I have tried the below method but it didn't work

```
df2 = df1[(df1['Value']!='Data Lost')]
df2 = df1[(df1['Value']!='I/O TimeOut')]
```

Would really appreciate any help!

Comment: You can try: `df2 = df1[df1['Value']!='Data Lost']` without round braces

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your df looks like:

```
   ID         Col1       date       Value
0  18     Gas Flow 2019-02-03         64↓
1  19  Temperature 2019-02-03         73↓
2  20          No2 2019-02-03     Medium↓
3  21          RPM 2019-02-03       1006↓
4  22    Vibration 2019-02-03         72↓
5  23          No2 2019-02-03  Data Lost↓
6  24     Gas Flow 2019-02-03         69↓
```

You can do [`series.str.contains()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html):

```
df1=df[~df.Value.str.contains('Data Lost',case=False,na=False)]
print(df1)

   ID         Col1       date    Value
0  18     Gas Flow 2019-02-03      64↓
1  19  Temperature 2019-02-03      73↓
2  20          No2 2019-02-03  Medium↓
3  21          RPM 2019-02-03    1006↓
4  22    Vibration 2019-02-03      72↓
6  24     Gas Flow 2019-02-03      69↓
```

Note: Use `case=False`  if you want the search to be case insensitive, also use `na=False` if you have `NaN` in the column.

Comment: how can Value column contains both integer as well as String values.. is its type object??

Comment: @hacker315 yes, because of the down arrow. anyways it is object when having int and str in a column